# OpenCV: Remove doubled contours on outlines of shapes without using RETR_EXTERNAL

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Open CV will register both an inner and an outer contour for an outline of a polygon.

Running with the test code below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def extract_contours():
    path = 'test.png'
    blank = np.zeros((184,184,3), np.uint8)
    blank[:] = (255,255,255)
    raw = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    raw = 255-raw
    img = cv2.cvtColor(raw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print(len(contours))
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 400: 
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
            cv2.drawContours(blank, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imwrite('contours.png', blank)

extract_contours()
```

On the image

[image: hollow square]

will yield two sets of contours on the outer and inner edge as shown in

[image: double contours]

Is there any fast way to collapse the two sets of contours into a single contour, preferably the average of the two? Using  I am fairly new to CV2 and computer vision in general so I don't know a lot of the tricks. I would rather not use `RETR_EXTERNAL` since I do not want to miss out on any nested shapes.

Comment: use `contourArea`, which gives a **signed** result. filter contours accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hierarchy` variable you defined *(when calling the `cv2.findContours` method)* to determine whether a contour is on the exterior of the outline or the interior:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def extract_contours():
    path = 'test.png'
    blank = np.zeros((184, 184, 3), np.uint8)
    blank[:] = (255, 255, 255)
    raw = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    raw = 255 - raw
    img = cv2.cvtColor(raw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt, hrc in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 400: 
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
            if hrc[2] < 0:
                cv2.drawContours(blank, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            elif hrc[3] < 0:
                cv2.drawContours(blank, [approx], 0, (0, 255, 0), 1)

    cv2.imwrite('contours.png', blank)

extract_contours()
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Drawing the contour in between the exterior and interior contours:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def extract_contours():
    path = 'test.png'
    blank = np.zeros((184, 184, 3), np.uint8)
    blank[:] = (255, 255, 255)
    raw = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    raw = 255 - raw
    img = cv2.cvtColor(raw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    exte = None
    inte = None
    for cnt, hrc in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 400: 
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
            if hrc[2] < 0:
                exte = approx.squeeze()
            elif hrc[3] < 0:
                inte = approx.squeeze()
    exte = exte[np.lexsort(exte.T)]
    inte = inte[np.lexsort(inte.T)]
    box = cv2.convexHull((exte[exte[:, 0].argsort()] + inte[inte[:, 0].argsort()]) // 2)
    cv2.drawContours(blank, [box], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2.imwrite('contours.png', blank)

extract_contours()
```

Resulting image:

[image]